# Composing two discontinuous functions into a continuous one

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Please help me think of an example of two discontinuous functions on $\mathbb R$ whose composition gives a continuous function on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: let $f(X)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(X)=\frac{1}{1-x} $ then fog is continuous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hints for a general process of producing such functions:**

1. The identity function $\mathrm{id}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, defined by $\mathrm{id}(x)=x$, is continuous.
2. Think of two non-trivial functions on $\mathbb{R}$ that, when composed, give the identity.
3. Define $f$ and $g$ to be those functions, except only applied to some subset $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ (for example, the irrationals), defining them to be the identity on $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$.

As long as the functions in step 2 map $S$ to itself, this (usually) produces discontinuous functions with the desired properties.

Some examples:

- Choose the function "multiply by $-1$", apply it to any subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ symmetric about the origin other than $\mathbb{R}$ itself.
- Choose the function "take reciprocals", apply it to any subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ which is closed under taking reciprocals.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}=g(x)$. You have $f(g(x))=\frac{1}{g(x)}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}=x$.

Comment: That's technically not a function on $\mathbb{R}$, since it's not defined at 0. Of course, for the purposes of the question, you can just define $f(0)=0$ and it's okay.

Comment: define it piecewise to be 0 at x=0 for both f and g

Comment: Great example, gracias.